# androidx renderscript crash "Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad"

Tags: android, renderscript, androidx, android-renderscript

I'm using [Android DS-Photo-Editor-SDK](https://github.com/DS-Photo-Editor-SDK) v1.5 ("ds-photo-editor-sdk-v6.aar") and androidx in my project.
I get the following error when opening the editor filters:

```
2018-10-26 19:36:27.949 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo: ----- class 'Landroidx/renderscript/RenderScript;' cl=0x16f0d598 -----
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   objectSize=492 (172 from super)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   access=0x8008.0001
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   vtable (71 entries, 11 in super):
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      0: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(int, long, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      1: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, int, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      2: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, int, int, java.lang.String)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.951 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      3: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      4: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, int, long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      5: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, android.graphics.Bitmap, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      6: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      7: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, long, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      8: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[], int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      9: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     10: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, float, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     11: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, int, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     12: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, long, long, byte[], int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     13: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, long, long, byte[], boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     14: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, long, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     15: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, int, byte[], long, int[], boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     16: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, android.graphics.Bitmap)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     17: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(long, android.view.Surface)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     18: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     19: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(long, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     20: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(long, int, android.graphics.Bitmap, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     21: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(long, int, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     22: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     23: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     24: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.c()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     25: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.d()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     26: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.e()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     27: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.f()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     28: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.finalize()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     29: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.g()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     30: android.content.Context androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.h()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     31: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.i()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     32: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.j()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     33: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nContextDeinitToClient(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     34: java.lang.String androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nContextGetErrorMessage(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     35: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nContextGetUserMessage(long, int[])
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     36: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nContextInitToClient(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     37: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nContextPeekMessage(long, int[])
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     38: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nDeviceCreate()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     39: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nIncDeviceCreate()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     40: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nIncLoadSO(int, java.lang.String)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     41: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nLoadIOSO()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     42: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nLoadSO(boolean, int, java.lang.String)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     43: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnAllocationCopyToBitmap(long, long, android.graphics.Bitmap)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     44: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnAllocationCreateBitmapBackedAllocation(long, long, int, android.graphics.Bitmap, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     45: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnAllocationCreateFromBitmap(long, long, int, android.graphics.Bitmap, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     46: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnAllocationCreateTyped(long, long, int, int, long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     47: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnAllocationSetSurface(long, long, android.view.Surface)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     48: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnContextCreate(long, int, int, int, java.lang.String)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     49: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnContextDestroy(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     50: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnContextFinish(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     51: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnElementCreate(long, long, int, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     52: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncAllocationCreateTyped(long, long, long, long, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     53: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncContextCreate(long, int, int, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     54: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncContextDestroy(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     55: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncContextFinish(long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     56: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncElementCreate(long, long, int, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     57: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncObjDestroy(long, long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     58: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnIncTypeCreate(long, long, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     59: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnObjDestroy(long, long)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     60: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptCCreate(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[], int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     61: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptForEach(long, long, long, int, long, long, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     62: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptForEach(long, long, long, int, long, long, byte[], boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     63: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptForEachClipped(long, long, long, int, long, long, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     64: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptForEachClipped(long, long, long, int, long, long, byte[], int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.961 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     65: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptIntrinsicCreate(long, int, long, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     66: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptSetVarF(long, long, int, float, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     67: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptSetVarI(long, long, int, int, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     68: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptSetVarObj(long, long, int, long, boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     69: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptSetVarVE(long, long, int, byte[], long, int[], boolean)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     70: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnTypeCreate(long, long, int, int, int, boolean, boolean, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   direct methods (10 entries):
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      0: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.<clinit>()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      1: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.<init>(android.content.Context)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      2: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(android.content.Context)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      3: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(android.content.Context, int, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$a, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      4: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(android.content.Context, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$a)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      5: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(android.content.Context, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$a, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      6: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(int, android.content.Context)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      7: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(android.content.Context, int, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$a, int)
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      8: void androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.k()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      9: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnSystemGetPointerSize()
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   static fields (13 entries):
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      0: java.lang.String androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.G
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      1: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.H
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      2: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.I
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      3: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.J
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      4: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.K
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      5: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      6: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      7: java.lang.Object androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.c
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      8: java.lang.reflect.Method androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.d
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      9: java.lang.reflect.Method androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.e
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     10: java.lang.Object androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.f
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     11: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.g
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     12: java.util.ArrayList androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.y
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:   instance fields (25 entries):
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      0: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.A
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      1: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.B
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      2: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.C
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      3: int androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.D
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      4: android.content.Context androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.E
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      5: java.lang.String androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.F
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      6: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.L
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      7: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$a androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.h
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      8: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.i
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:      9: long androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.j
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     10: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.k
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     11: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.l
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     12: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$b androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.m
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     13: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.n
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     14: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.o
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     15: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.p
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     16: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.q
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     17: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.r
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     18: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.s
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     19: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.t
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     20: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.u
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     21: androidx.renderscript.c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.v
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     22: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$d androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.w
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     23: androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$c androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.x
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo:     24: boolean androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.z
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/software.photo: Failed to register native method androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.nDeviceDestroy(J)V in base.apk
2018-10-26 19:36:27.962 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/RenderScript_jni: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.levionsoftware.photos-hK41CtPwRAeB732oYDGtHw==/lib/arm/librsjni_androidx.so"

    --------- beginning of crash
2018-10-26 19:36:27.996 16826-16898/com.levionsoftware.photos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GeoResolverLoadingTask
    Process: com.levionsoftware.photos, PID: 16826
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: androidx.renderscript.h: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.levionsoftware.photos-hK41CtPwRAeB732oYDGtHw==/lib/arm/librsjni_androidx.so" Support lib API: 2301
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(Unknown Source:196)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source:35)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.c.a.a(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.b.a$b.a(Unknown Source:58)
        at com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.b.a$b.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2018-10-26 19:36:28.053 16826-16897/com.levionsoftware.photos W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2018-10-26 19:36:28.059 16826-16897/com.levionsoftware.photos D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2018-10-26 19:37:03.749 16826-16835/com.levionsoftware.photos E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2018-10-26 19:37:03.769 16826-16835/com.levionsoftware.photos E/System: androidx.renderscript.g: Calling RS with no Context active.
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.f(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.c(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.k(Unknown Source:15)
        at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.finalize(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I followed the instructions and added this to my bradle.build:

```
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" // Gradle 3.2.0 known issues: Although you typically don't need to specify the build tools version, when using Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0 with renderscriptSupportModeEnabled set to true, you need to include the following in each module's build.gradle file:    android.buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
renderscriptTargetApi 21
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

other arguments:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 28

sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${supportxLibVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${supportxLibVersion}"
//implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${supportxLibVersion}"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:${supportxLibVersion}"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2"
// MultiDex
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

Does someone know how to fix that?
I can't find any solution on Google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it. Add these lines to proguard:

```
# RenderScript
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Comment: I didn't need the first bit, but the keep class did the trick. Thank you :)

Comment: Are you talking about proguard-rules.pro? I added these lines in this file but still getting crash

Comment: I am not targeting to AndroidX So what i have to do?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. thanks for the wonderful solution.

Comment: Use second line and it works.