# Inflate exception occurs when using custom view

Tags: android

I am using a [custom view](https://github.com/armcha/ColoredShadowImageView) on this layout. There is no error/exception occurs when run in debug mode. But when I generate a signed APK and try to run the app, the following exception occurs.

Exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in hdfhtt.pastel.app:layout/item_icon
```

item_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- License ... (Line 2 > 18) -->
<!-- Line 19: --><io.github.armcha.coloredshadow.ShadowImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute"
    app:shadowColor="@color/shadow" />
```

I already add the [proguard rules](https://github.com/armcha/ColoredShadowImageView#add-proguard-rules-if-necessary) and still don't fix the problem.

Full stack trace as requested:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: hdfhtt.pastel.app, PID: 27820
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class io.github.armcha.coloredshadow.ShadowImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class io.github.armcha.coloredshadow.ShadowImageView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at dev.jahir.frames.extensions.views.ViewKt.inflate(Unknown Source:10)
    at dev.jahir.frames.extensions.views.ViewKt.inflate$default(Unknown Source:5)
    at dev.jahir.blueprint.ui.adapters.IconsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:9)
    at dev.jahir.blueprint.ui.adapters.IconsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.createViewHolder(Unknown Source:5)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.k(:38)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.c(:3)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(Unknown Source:95)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(:2)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(:4)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(:2)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown Source:38)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(Unknown Source:65)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at e.e.e.a.onMeasure(Unknown Source:80)
    at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.onMeasure(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.measureChildWithDecorationsAndMargin(Unknown Source:19)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.measureChild(Unknown Source:92)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(Unknown Source:202)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(:2)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(:4)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(:2)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown Source:38)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(Unknown Source:37)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(Unknown Source:5)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.C(:6)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.k(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(:2)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:944)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2907)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7745)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:31)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:131)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:125)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:101)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(Unknown Source:140)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: e.v.g: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/hdfhtt.pastel.app-7Q02IAY5snxCTOrOqyrlBg==/lib/arm64/librsjni_androidx.so" Support lib API: 2301
    at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.b(:2)
    at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.a(:2)
    at io.github.armcha.coloredshadow.ShadowImageView.<init>(:1)
    ... 96 more
```

Comment: I think api  already depriacted

Comment: @sashabeliy but it works fine on debug

Comment: @HadifHatta Post the full `Logcat` error...

Comment: @Vishnu i have updated the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [androidx renderscript crash "Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI\_ERR returned from JNI\_OnLoad"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013840/androidx-renderscript-crash-error-loading-rs-jni-library-java-lang-unsatisfied)

Comment: @Bek I have tried but still got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found a solution by changing this,

```
proguardFiles 'proguard-android-optimize.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

To this,

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
```